# Grunt config with es6

Tags: gruntjs, ecmascript-6

It is possible to write grunt config files in es6 like this?

```
//Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  var arr = [1,2,3];
  arr.forEach(val => {
    ...
  });
  ...
}
```

Comment: You can always transpile your gruntfile to ES5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to do this painlessly is to use Babel's `babel-register` module like this:

Installation:

`npm install babel-register --save-dev`

.babelrc:

```
{
    presets: ["es2015"]
}
```

Gruntfile.js:

```
require('babel-register')

module.exports = require('./Gruntfile.es').default
```

Gruntfile.es

```
export default function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GruntJS is a javascript based application. It runs under the node/iojs process and adheres to the capabilities of that environment. If you use iojs or a node version that supports these features, then yes, its possible.

Comment: How i can set my node to support these features?